# Node JS setInterval. TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: .net, node.js, timer, error-handling

I am Nowfal, a c# programmer. I am new in Node JS.
When I create a function and gave inside setInterval an error occured as 
TypeError: Cannot read Property 'apply' of undefined

at wrapper [as _onTimeout] (timers.js:274:13)

at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:119:15)

My code  pages are given below

**Page 1(Server.js)**

```
var db = require('./dbConnect.js');
var ins = require('./dbInsert.js');

var tagId = [];
var schoolInfoId = [];
var imeNo = [];
var totalRows = 0;

function ViewQuery() {
    var mysql = db.mysql;
    var connection = db.createMyConnection();


    connection.connect();


    var mycommand = "SELECT     t.skha_tag_id_no,s.skha_school_info_id,a.skha_out_device_imeno" +
        " FROM skha_tag t INNER JOIN skha_student_info s on skha_tag_id     = skha_student_tag_id_no " +
         " INNER JOIN skha_student_school_attendance a on     a.skha_student_info_id = s.skha_student_info_id" +
         " WHERE DATE(skha_student_in_time) = CURDATE() AND     skha_student_out_time IS NULL and skha_out_status = 1 ";

     connection.query(mycommand, function (err, rows) {
        if (!err) {

         var result;
            for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                totalRows++;

                result = rows[i];

                tagId.push(result['skha_tag_id_no']);
                schoolInfoId.push(result['skha_school_info_id']);
                imeNo.push(result['skha_out_device_imeno']);

            }


            for (i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) {
                ins.insertDB(tagId[i], schoolInfoId[i], imeNo[i]);
            }

        }
        else
            console.log('Error while performing Query.');
    });

    connection.end();

};

setInterval(ViewQuery(),30000); //Error Generating from here
```

**Page 2(dbConnect.js)**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

exports.createMyConnection = function createMyConnection() {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection( {
        host    : '192.168.0.175',
        user    : 'ss_user',
        password : 'df33-ccff2188',
        database : 'shkaliasdb',
        multipleStatements: true
    });
    return connection;
}

exports.mysql = mysql;
```

**Page 3 (dbInsert.js)**

```
var db = require('./dbConnect.js');

var logOutTimeInterval = 5;
exports.insertDB = function (RFID, schoolID, imei) {

    var mysql = db.mysql;
    var connection = db.createMyConnection();

    connection.connect();
    console.log('IMEI : ' + imei);
    console.log(RFID);



    str = "SET @OutStatus=0;SET @logOutTime=0;call     out_mark_save_two_device('" + RFID + "'," + schoolID + "," +      logOutTimeInterval + ",@OutStatus,@logOutTime," + imei + ")";

    console.log(str);


    connection.query(str, function (err, rows, fields) {//, fields
        if (err)
            console.log('Error while performing Query.' + err);
         else {
            console.log(rows[0]);

        }
    });

    connection.end();


};
```

First time code works correctly and then shows error message, timer not working.

Please give me any solution for this...
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-sql.html).

**NEVER** use string concatenation to build a SQL query. **ALWAYS** use a parameterized query.

Comment: Thanks Richard Deeming.. I know problem of this query. When I implement this in real time, I will avoid that.  But, I could not get any solution for my actual issue. Can you help me in that?

Answer (score -2):

Show code from timers.js.
You call "apply" method from undefined object. Method "apply" work

Comment: I have not written code for timers.js. It will map automatically to the project, when creating project